# Can you damage a tantalum capacitor by mounting with heat gun?

Tags: capacitor

I just mounted some 47uF tantalum capacitors to a logic board. I used a heat gun at 325°C to heat them up so the solder under there would melt, and then they would sit down on their pads. They did successfully mount, but I was concerned about the heat gun damaging the caps because they became very hot, and one or two of them became discolored (slightly toasted :D). The machine boots fine.

Comment: Which capacitors? The data sheet would have specs on the soldering processes that it can survive.

Comment: You can damage a tantalum capacitor by smiling at it  suggestively...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any component can be damaged by too much heat.  Factories carefully control the temperature of their "solder reflow ovens" to ride that balance between properly soldering the part and destroying it.  It is more than just temperature that they control, it is the time or speed at which a part is brought up to a temp, how long it stays there, and then how quickly it cools.  Some ovens have 7 or more zones, each with their own temperature controls, just for this purpose.

The problem with a heat gun is that you have no real control over anything.  While the gun might be set for 325 deg C, you have no idea how hot the parts were getting, or how fast.  Could the heat gun have damaged the parts?  Absolutely.  But it could also have worked, too.

There are these things called "hot air reflow solder stations", which is essentially an expensive heat gun designed for doing things like this.  It has lots of controls for soldering parts without damaging them.

When it comes to caps, there really isn't any reason to use a heat gun-- or even a hot air reflow solder station.  There are only two pins, which are relatively big.  Even if the PCB was done wrong, there are always ways to hack a cap on there.

The only parts that I can't solder with a standard soldering iron are BGA's, and some QFN's with the E-Pad on the bottom.  Everything else, TSSOP's, TQFP's, etc., I can just use a standard iron.

Comment: Well it was a lot easier to remove the old caps with the hot air gun. I figured I'd use it for adding the replacements too, since I was out of flux and my attempts at using regular solder were not seeming to work like I expected. The solder was beading up on the end of the raw solder piece, as opposed to going down onto the pads. I am guessing it's because I need that wonderful flux. So best I go buy some!

Comment: @DarkGoob While it is easier to remove old parts (caps, chips, etc.) with a heat gun, you don't have good control over what gets heated.  It is possible to remove the caps, but damage other things.  Flux is your friend.  Use it often, and lots.  Beware, however, that SOME flux can be conductive and needs to be removed.

Comment: @DarkGoob, there's a reason they make rosin-core solder.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm  Often times, especially with surface mount components, the flux that is inside the solder is not enough.  In my lab I have extra flux in little bottles, and I use it liberally and frequently.  When exposed to air and heat, flux becomes ineffective quickly.  If you don't get the thing soldered down quickly the flux becomes worthless and you need to add more.  With SMT parts, it often takes longer to solder down the part than the "useful time" of the flux and more flux is the only thing that can help.

Comment: Yep, rosin-core is what I have and it ain't working. Going to get some flux but they don't have it at the Shack, except in paste form (?). The liquid kind was what was in all the youtube SM videos. OK. Going to find it.

Comment: The paste works, @DarkGoob. If the flux wasn't even sticking to your pen, though, it means the pen is oxidized -- tin it.